# problem understanding Lagrange's continued fraction theorem

Tags: quadratics, irrational-numbers, continued-fractions

here is some problems I have in the following proof from **Diophantine Analysis** by Jorn Steuding with a little change:

> A continued fraction denoted $\zeta$ is periodic if and only if it's a quadratic irrational,e.g. a continued fraction which is eventually periodic represents a numbers that is a root of a quadratic equation.

$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]\Longrightarrow $ this is known as **Euler's continued fraction theorem** and is easy to prove.

$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]\Longleftarrow $ this is known as  **Lagrange's continued fraction theorem,** and the proof is as follows :

> since $\zeta$ is quadratic irrational implies there exist a irreducible quadratic equation $P(x)=ax^2+bx+c$ with $a,b,c \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $a\ne 0$ such that :$$P(\zeta)=a\zeta^2+b\zeta+c=0$$
>   on the other hand since $\zeta$ is irrational therefore its continued fraction is infinite,e.g.  $\zeta=[a_0;a_1,...]$
>
> and we have:
>   $$\zeta=\frac{\zeta_np_{n-1}+p_{n-2}}{\zeta_nq_{n-1}+q_{n-2}} \qquad(\small n\geq 2)$$
>
> Substituting the above relation in the polynomial we get :
>
> $$A_n\zeta_n^2 +B_n\zeta_n +C_n=0$$
>
> where $$\large A_n=ap^2_{n-1}+bp_{n-1}q_{n-1}+cq^2_{n-1}$$
>   $$\large B_n=2ap_{n-1}p_{n-2}+b(p_{n-1}q_{n-2}+p_{n-2}q_{n-1})+2cq_{n-1}q_{n-2}$$
>   $$\large C_n=ap^2_{n-2}+bp_{n-2}q_{n-2}+cq^2_{n-2}$$
>
> clearly $A_n,B_n,C_n \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $A_n \ne 0$ if $A_n = 0$ would imply that $\large \frac{p_{n−2}}{q_{n−2}}$is a root of $P(x)$ contradicting
>   the irreducibility of $P$ Thus, $A_nx^2+B_nx+C_n$ is an irreducible quadratic
>   polynomial with root $\zeta_n$.

here is the first problem I have, where did actually $\large \frac{p_{n−2}}{q_{n−2}}$ come from?

> also $B^2_n− 4A_nC_n = (b^2 − 4ac) (p_{n−1}q_{n−2} − p_{n−2}q_{n−1})=\pm(b^2 − 4ac)...$

here is the second problem, how we can calculate $B^2_n− 4A_nC_n$?it looks hard to calculate and indeed takes much time, I guess there should be another way, notice that I know the fact $(p_{n−1}q_{n−2} − p_{n−2}q_{n−1})=(-1)^{n-1}$

Comment: Numerator and denominator of the convergents can be defined recursively, hence they can be calculated with $O(n)$ operations. We must start with $2$ values and recursively can then get the rest. Of course, we also need the entries of the continued fraction.

Comment: can you explain more with details?

Comment: The convergents are $\frac{p_n}{q_n}$ and we have $p_n=a_n\cdot p_{n-1}+p_{n-2}$ and analogue for $q_n$ , if $a_n$ are the entries of the continued fraction. If we have the first two convergents, we can calculate all the others this way. See http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Convergent.html for more details.

Comment: I got it, as I know we have $p_0=a_0,q_0=1$ and $p_1=a_1a_0+1,q_1=a_1$, and the others as you mentioned can be defined recursively.

Comment: Also posted to MO, https://mathoverflow.net/questions/342417/problem-in-lagrange-theorem