# Prove the continued fraction of $\sqrt{n}$ has a period.

Tags: continued-fractions

I want to know the proof that the continued fraction of $\sqrt{n}$ has a period.

[This question and answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/298040/continued-fractions-periodicity-and-convolution) prove that when the continued fraction has a period, it can be represented by quadratic form. However, it doesn't prove that the continued fraction of quadratic form have a period. According to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_continued_fraction), Lagrange prove it.

"Amazingly, Lagrange's discovery implies that the canonical continued fraction expansion of the square root of every non-square integer is periodic"

Does anybody know how to prove this?

Comment: use this link https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3369147/problem-understanding-lagranges-continued-fraction-theorem

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to read [the posts](https://crypto.stanford.edu/pbc/notes/contfrac/definition.html) of Ben Lynn on continued fractions. In particular, in the second theorem of [this post](https://crypto.stanford.edu/pbc/notes/contfrac/periodic.html), he proves what you are basically asking.

The sketch of the prove is the following:

1. Show that tail fractions $x_k=[a_k, a_{k+1},\ldots]$ of the number $\sqrt{n}=x=[a_0;a_1,a_2,\ldots]$ are the roots of a quadratic equation $Az^2+Bz+C=0$ with integer coefficients.
2. Show that coefficients $A$, $B$, $C$ are bounded, i.e. $|A|,|B|,|C|<f(x)$.
3. Since $A,B,C$ are integer and bounded, the number of possible equations $Az^2+Bz+C=0$ is finite, and so is the number of possible values for $x_k$.
4. That means for some $k,m$: $x_k=x_m$, which means the continued fraction has to repeat itself.

Comment: Thank you. How he get $|ru-ts|=1$?

Comment: By induction you can show that $\begin{pmatrix}p_n&p_{n-1}\\q_n&q_{n-1}\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}a_0&1\\1&0\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}a_1&1\\1&0\end{pmatrix}\cdots\begin{pmatrix}a_n&1\\1&0\end{pmatrix}$. Taking the determinant, you show that $p_nq_{n-1}-p_{n-1}q_n=(-1)^n$